# MySql. Не работает ROUND

Tags: mysql

Написал функцию в mysql(calculate_price), где считается цена и возвращается, перед самым возвращением, итоговую цену округляю ROUNDом.
Но функция возвращает не округленный FLOAT. Но если вызывать вот так "SELECT ROUND( calculate_price(some_id_price), 2 )" тогда все работает. А мне нужно чтобы функция самостоятельно возвращала уже округленное число.

Comment: _самостоятельно возвращала уже округленное число_ - это как. если не `ROUND( calculate_price(some_id_price), 2)`? В чем вообще у вас проблема с `ROUND()`?

Comment: @Regent Я в теле функции возвращаю число(RETURN ROUND(OUT_PRICE,2);), но на выходе я получяю что то вроде 12.48466865

Comment: @СергейДеревянко, по вашему описанию ошибка [не воспроизводится](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9ea2d/1). возможно, вы упустили какой-то существенный фактор.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Вот скриншот вашего кода, на моей локальной машине. http://joxi.ru/Q2KxwOPS7jNdAj Наверно это, что то у меня на серваке творится...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin только что проделал то же самое на удаленке. Результат тот же самый, не округляет...

Answer (score 1):

В общем вопрос остается не решенным, но я выпутался тем, что объявил возвращаемый результат не float а decimal(8,2)

Comment: Дело в том, что float - это число с плавающей запятой. В computer sience общеизвестен факт, что невозможно представить число с плавающей запятой с абсолютной точностью. Поэтому для денежных значений рекомендуется использовать decimal.